# Question about terminology of Munkres's Analysis on Manifold text

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image]

The definition above are given by Munkres when he defined Euclidean manifold.  One question I have about terminology is that when he says " For each $p \in M$, there is an open set $V$ of $M$ ..... ",  then is the set $V$ open in $M$ or is it open in $ \mathbb{R^n} $?  or does it matter at all???

also, by his def, then a 2-manifold in $\mathbb{R^3} $ would be a surface, is that correct??? thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The set $V$ is open in $M$; typically this is defined to mean that there's an open set $W$ in $\mathbb R^n$ whose intersection with $M$ is $V$ (i.e., $M$ has the "relative topology").
2. A 2-manifold in 3-space is indeed a surface (or surface with boundary, like a closed disk, if the space $\mathbb H^k$ is also allowed as a target for coordinate patches).